# how to add google review with carousel

Tags: javascript, google-api, review

I want to add `Google review` with `carousel slide` in my website.

I already get reviews, but i want to show that reviews in `carousel-slide`.

This is my code:

//HTML

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
     <div id="google-reviews"></div> <!-- Google review here -->
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="row" style="padding: 20px">
        <button style="border: none;"><i class="fa fa-quote-left testimonial_fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        <p class="testimonial_para">
        Lorem Ipsum ist ein einfacher Demo-Text für die Print- und Schriftindustrie. Lorem Ipsum ist in der Industrie bereits der Standard Demo-Text "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo en.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

//JS
`google-places.js`

```
<script>
var renderReviews = function(reviews){
    reviews = sort_by_date(reviews);
    reviews = filter_minimum_rating(reviews);
    var html = "";
    var row_count = (plugin.settings.max_rows > 0)? plugin.settings.max_rows - 1 : reviews.length - 1;
    // make sure the row_count is not greater than available records
    row_count = (row_count > reviews.length-1)? reviews.length -1 : row_count;

    for (var i = row_count; i >= 0; i--) {
        var stars = renderStars(reviews[i].rating);
        var date = convertTime(reviews[i].time);
        html = html+"<div class='review-item'><div class='review-meta'><span class='review-author'>"+reviews[i].author_name+"</span><span class='review-sep'>, </span><span class='review-date'>"+date+"</span></div>"+stars+"<p class='review-text'>"+reviews[i].text+"</p></div>"
        console.log(html);
    };

    $element.append(html);
}
</script>
```

how can i septate `html` values?

Demo carousel link  https://codepen.io/nikhil/pen/NqmQag

Answer (score 1):

I have modified this script and this is working fine for me. Just add active class for first item because carousel set `display none;` for all items.

```
 var renderReviews = function(reviews){
        reviews = sort_by_date(reviews);
        reviews = filter_minimum_rating(reviews);
        var html = "";
        var row_count = (plugin.settings.max_rows > 0)? plugin.settings.max_rows - 1 : reviews.length - 1;
        // make sure the row_count is not greater than available records
        row_count = (row_count > reviews.length-1)? reviews.length -1 : row_count;
        var counter=0;
        var active='';
        for (var i = row_count; i >= 0; i--) {
            if(counter==0){ active='active'; } else { active='' }
            var stars = renderStars(reviews[i].rating);
            var date = convertTime(reviews[i].time);
            html = html+"<div class='item "+active+"'><div class='review-meta'><span class='review-author'>"+reviews[i].author_name+"</span><span class='review-sep'>, </span><span class='review-date'>"+date+"</span></div>"+stars+"<p class='review-text'>"+reviews[i].text+"</p></div>"
            //console.log(html);
            counter++;
        };

        $element.append(html);
    }
```